# How can I restore the initial value of outline for :focus?

Tags: css

The vast majority of `a`s in my application have a custom `:focus` style, and so they have `outline: none`. However, in some cases I don't have a good custom alternative, and I want to override my custom style and use the browser's default focus style.

I tried using:

```
div.where-i-want-this-style a:focus {
  outline: initial;
}
```

But this didn't give me an outline. In fact, when I remove the `outline: none;` from higher up the cascade and toggle this line, I see that this line actually causes the outline to *go away*.

My theory is that `initial` here actually uses the initial outline of the `a`, not of a *focused* `a`. That value is, essentially, `none`.

Is there a value I can provide that means something like `outline: default-focus-outline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `:not()` to remove the default outline from all links except the class you want.

```
a:not(.default-outline):focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Here's a **[full example](http://jsfiddle.net/nb59w/2/)**

Comment: This isn't a wonderful solution (since I have to keep that selector in sync with each exception), but it does appear to be the only remotely cross-browser solution.

Comment: @Peeja Pretty much, except for <= ie8. Better than i thought actually.

Answer (score 6):

For the record, something I found to work in Chrome, but not Firefox:

```
a:focus {
  outline-style: none;
}

div.where-i-want-this-style a:focus {
  outline-style: auto;
}
```

This works because Chrome's initial value for `outline-style` is pretty straightforward (`auto`), and setting just that part to `none` is enough to disable the default outline.

Unfortunately, Firefox appears to use a vastly different method for setting its default focus style. If I'm reading Firebug right, it may not be expressible in CSS, which means there's no way to get it back once it's overridden. Once I discovered that I didn't bother checking any other browsers.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for firefox?

Comment: It's been a while, but it looks like the accepted answer worked in FF, though it's not as nice. I don't think I found a solution like this one that worked in FF.

Comment: I need to override 3rd party code with new CSS, but i cant edit the 3rd party code. For this reason that answer wont work for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you define outline styles and want to ‘revert’ back to the default User Agent styles on :focus, this will help. You will find cross-browser issues using the initial property such as .myClass:focus{outline: initial;}... I recommend this one instead:

```
.myClass:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted #212121;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}
```

Hope this helps!!